# Textarea не дружит с value

Tags: html, php

Доброго всем времени суток.

```
<textarea name="mess" rows="7" cols="50" maxlength="1000" value="<? echo "123".$mod; ?>"></textarea>
```

1. Почему значение в value не отображается?
2. Может ли кто подсказать способ (а лучше 2), организовать отображение нужного текста /  переменной в textarea? (В идеале без JS.)

Comment: @mixalef `textarea` может принимать значение `value` если к нему обращаться от javascript, но атрибута такого не имеет!

Comment: это я в курсе (т.к. перед тем как спросить - гуглю). по этому указал в теме, что интересует вариант без JS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<textarea name="mess" rows="7" cols="50" maxlength="1000"><? echo "123".$mod; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea name="mess" rows="7" cols="50" maxlength="1000"><? echo "123".$mod; ?></textarea>
```

невероятно! ткнул наугад!

Comment: невероятно! :D